# Horizantal Bar with Plus image at center?

Tags: html, css

I am designing a page which required a horizontal Bar with Plus image at center. Lke this,
[image]

I have tried this,

```
<div><img src="http://s7.postimage.org/z6jiogw6f/add_icon.png" /></div>

div{
    background: #ced8e7;
    padding: 1px 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

But the bar is not circular and plus image is completely inside of Bar. Can anyone help? Sample, http://jsfiddle.net/PSAEJ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it will work tested :

**Updated :**
[jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/amaluk/6/watch)

Comment: How to make it circular at edges?

Comment: @surinder - you can't define `margin-left:-27px` static. Because not all the resolution will make the image center.

Comment: @PankitKapadia i have added margin-top and margin-bottom -27px . not margin-left ..

Comment: @Surinder - thats in an updated code !! i saw it !! and now it is correct !

Comment: Still the bar is not circular/curved from edges

Comment: in which browser u are opening page ?

Comment: I think the bottom approach is more appropriate. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you: You just needed to wrap your img tag into another `<div>`

http://jsfiddle.net/ZkDXA/2

Edit:
You really don't need an extra `div` if you prefer not to. Another example http://jsfiddle.net/ESt84/

Answer (score 1):

set overflow property to visible or remove (default `overflow: visible`) and give -ve margin to your image

```
div {
    background: #ced8e7;
    padding: 1px 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    height: 7px;
    margin-top: 5px; }

img {
    margin-top: -7px; }
```

Updated **jsfiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/PSAEJ/10/